# c segfault in function log_init

Tags: c, database, malloc

I am trying to create a database in c and I am trying to figure out what is going on in a simplified version.
Now hear this: No matter what value I assign N to be (which is the size of database measured in logs) I get a segfault in the third entry,even if N is 1! (or 1000).
There is no way of knowing which chunk of prohibetted memory is parsed because all that gdb reports is the line of code that the exception occured.Seems like debugging is useless here.What am I doing wrong? Thank you all in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 1 //the initial size of the database
#define STRLIM 30 

typedef struct log{
    int id;
}log_t;

typedef struct index{
    int sarcount;
    int sarcap;
}index_t;

log_t* init_log(log_t** log,index_t* index);
int printList(log_t** log,index_t* index);
int menu(void);

log_t* init_log(log_t** cat,index_t* index){
    cat[index->sarcount]->id=index->sarcount;
    
    index->sarcount++;
    return *cat;
}

int menu(void){
    printf("1. Insert a new log\n");
    printf("5. Exit\n");   
    printf("6. Print the list\n");
    return 0;
}//just prints the menu 

int printList(log_t** cat,index_t* index){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<index->sarcount;i++){
        printf("#%dID:%d\n",i,cat[i]->id);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{  
    log_t* log=malloc(sizeof(log_t)*N);
        if(!log){
            perror("failed to malloc:");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    index_t* index=malloc(sizeof(index_t));
    index->sarcount=0;


int choice=0;
      while(1){
        menu();
          scanf("%d", &choice);
    if(choice==1){
       printf("enter a log\n");     
    log=init_log(&log,index);  
    }
   
    if(choice==5){
        printf("exiting now\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if(choice==6){
        system("clear");
        printf("printing all existing movies:\n");
        printList(&log,index);
     }
  }//end of while 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Address Sanitizer is a tool that helps debug memory access errors (more info available with a google search). Just add `-fsanitize=address` to your compilation command to use it.

Comment: first problem: `log_t* log=malloc(sizeof(log_t*)*N);` --> `log_t* log=malloc(sizeof(*log)*N);`, you always want to `malloc` memory "one level up" from the lvalue you're assigning it to. In this case, you're `malloc`ing for a `log_t*` so your `sizeof` operand should be a `log_t`, which is what `*log` is. But also in this case, you're probably allocating more space than you need, since `int`s are probably 4 bytes and pointers are probably 8 bytes.. depends on your system.

Comment: @yano , yes of course your are correct, thank you. Did so many tests and different versions that I forgot to post the correct one.

Comment: doubt it's the problem, but `printList` doesn't return a value. Furthermore, `printList` doesn't need to return a value, neither does `menu` (the return value is unconditional and you're not using it). Might as well make those functions `void`.

Comment: @yano, yes, after changing it to "void" no effect in the program's behaviour.

Comment: "all that gdb reports is the line of code that the exception occured" ... Please include this information in your question

Answer (score 1):

I'm not even sure of the right terminology to describe it, but you're abstracting one more level than you should be passing the parameters to your functions.  When you do

```
log_t* log=malloc(sizeof(log_t)*N);
```

You're reserving memory to `N` `log_t`s, and `log` points to them:

```
           ______________________________________
log -----> | log_t 0 | log_t 1 | ... | log_t N-1|
           --------------------------------------
```

When you pass `&log` to `init_log` (and `printList`), you're passing a *pointer* of `log` to those functions.  So you have:

```
cat ------> log -------> (as above)
```

Now, when you do `cat[index->sarcount]`, you're dereferencing an index of cat.  However, `cat` only has a length of 1, it only points to one `log_t*`.  Anything more than `cat[0]` is out of bounds.  `log` is the pointer that points to `log_t` objects with dimensionality beyond 0.  So you need to do something like

```
cat ------> log[index-sarcount]
```

to select the appropriate log.  As suggested in the other answer, you could do that like:

```
(*cat)[index->sarcount].id = index->sarcount;
```

Here, `(*cat)` always dereferences to the first (and only) instance of `log_t*` it points to, and `[index->sarcount]` dereferences the actual `log_t` object (max of `N-1`) you want to modify.

But, having said all that, that extra level of indirection is really unnecessary.  I would change your function prototypes to

```
void init_log(log_t** log,index_t* index); // well ok, still using log_t** here. Don't have to, but I consider that better practice than returning a log_t
void printList(log_t* log,index_t* index);
```

And then these functions would look like:

```
void init_log(log_t** cat,index_t* index){
    (*cat)[index->sarcount].id=index->sarcount;
    
    index->sarcount++;
}

void printList(log_t* cat,index_t* index){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<index->sarcount;i++){
        printf("#%dID:%d\n",i,cat[i].id);
        // for your current `printList` function, this would need to be
        //printf("#dID:%d\n", i, (*cat)[i].id);
    }
}
```

And then you would call them like

```
init_log(&log,index);
printList(log,index);
```

[An example](https://godbolt.org/z/bMe7Gvhrb)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in init_log and printList function.

Try the below changes

In init_log

change `cat[index->sarcount]->id=index->sarcount;` to `(*cat + index->sarcount)->id = index->sarcount;`

In printList

change `printf("#%dID:%d\n",i,cat[i]->id);` to `printf("#%dID:%d\n",i,(*cat + i)->id);`

Also I would suggest you to change the structs like below (remove log and index name):

```
typedef struct{
    int id;
}log_t;

typedef struct{
    int sarcount;
    int sarcap;
}index_t;
```